# Error when opening xml file in python 3 with sublime text 3

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, sqlite

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\diamo\Documents\Sublime Text Saves\ItunesDatabase.py", line 50, in <module>
    stuff = ET.parse(fname)
  File "C:\Users\diamo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1183, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\diamo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 583, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:/Users/diamo/Desktop/Library.xml'
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

Here is the essential bits of the code:

```
import sqlite3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

fname = '‪C:/Users/diamo/Desktop/Library.xml'  #input('Music Data Filename: ')
if (len(fname) < 1): fname = 'C:/Users/diamo/Desktop/Library.xml'

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  I'm not sure how it got there but as I was moving my blinky vertical bar across the text piece by piece, I found that before all the words I had to press twice to make it move, meaning there was a character at the beginning not taking up any space.  I deleted it and now my program is working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your filename has a unicode character `\u202a` on the front of it which is confusing the `open` command in the `parse` method. You may have a problem in how you are storing/retrieving your filename.

It looks like that character specifies that this is a Left-To-Right string (opposed to Right-to-Left text such as Arabic). I can't say I know why this is being inserted in your string though.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a bit.  Do you have any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: I was able to remove that character by decoding it to unicode and indexing from the second character onward: `fname.decode('utf-8')[1:]`. Seems like a really hacky solution though

Comment: It may be helpful to know where these file paths are coming from, because it may be a configuration option.