# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument, opening a file in python

Tags: python

I want to open a file and although I have given its address correctly, an error appears when I run the program.

This is my code:

```
file1 = open('‪‪C:\pronouns.txt‪', 'r')
```

This is the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202a\u202aC:\\pronouns.txt\u202a'
```

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite the filename, to make sure you don't get those Unicode characters first and last? And in line of code you show, are you really using a *single* back-slash inside that string?

Comment: Try this : `file1 = open('‪‪C:\\pronouns.txt‪', 'r')` or `file1 = open('‪‪C:/pronouns.txt‪', 'r')`

Comment: Try renaming the file!

Comment: What do you mean by rewriting the program?

Comment: It didn't change

Comment: Not rewrite the program, rewrite the *string*, or possible the whole *line* itself.

Comment: I have even tried it with different files, but the problem was still there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove u202a from Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267999/remove-u202a-from-python-string)

Comment: Also, considering the link from @Guy, try to change editor.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I tried to copy filename directly from win10 file security properties dialog.

Here's [Why is there an invisible U+202A at the start of my file name?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924) helped me out, and maybe helpful to you as well.

The mysterious Unicode character "\u202a" is a formatting control character that means "LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING" which is used to force text to be interpreted as left-to-right. However, it's invisible, if you try to copy the text out of the dialog box, the Unicode formatting control character comes along for a ride and may create all sorts of silent confusion.So, just input file path manually.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Forward and Backward slashes are always tricky. Can you try

```py
file1 = open('‪‪C:/pronouns.txt‪', 'r')
```

Comment: OP is using `Windows`, where you have backward slashes!

Comment: Yeah, both forward and backward slashes will work. It must be a typo in filename

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Windows have been able to use forward slashes since the DOS days.

Answer (score 0):

```
file1 = open('‪‪C:\pronouns.txt‪', 'r').
```

rename the first character your file with capital

```
file1 = open('‪‪C:\Pronouns.txt‪', 'r')
```