# How to import an excel sheet by taking the file location as input (using Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to learn Pandas. I usually import the excel sheet using :

```html
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Comp\Documents\filename.xlsx')
```

But I was hoping to make the user input the file location on their own. 
I tried taking the file location as the input and using the format option but it didn't really work for me. Here is what I've tried :

```html
print("Do you have another sheet for a new DF?")
ch = input("Press Y or N")
if ch =="Y":
    df2 = pd.read_excel (r'{}'.format(input("copy and paste the location of the excel file here ")))
```

I was just taking a hit-and-run trial here to see if it works.
This is the error that I got :
 [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:\Users\Ashu\Documents\Book1.xlsx'

Please let me know how I can achieve this task. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information what is going on:
[Remove u202a from Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267999/remove-u202a-from-python-string)

You could do the following:

```
print("Do you have another sheet for a new DF?")
ch = input("Press y or n")

if ch =="y":
    filePath = input("copy and paste the location of the excel file here ")
    filePath = filePath.strip("‪u202a")
    df2 = pd.read_excel (r'{}'.format(filePath))
```