# c# and python no longer able to find files

Tags: python, c#, directory

***PROBLEM SOLVED BY RETYPING***

I am suddenly no longer able to find files in c# or python. I have a simple program that attempts to read a file in both c# and python.

I have posted both c# and python code, as I think this problem probably is not in the actual code but in some system configuration on my computer. Has anyone experienced something similar and know what the cause of this issue may be?

Thank you in advance, code follows below:

When I run the following c# code, it appears that c# is reading @"‪C:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt"

as

'C:\Users\nkla\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\‪C:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt''

```
        string testValue = @"‪C:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt";

        var enumLines = File.ReadLines(testValue);
```

**Error received:**

System.IO.IOException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Users\nkla\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\‪C:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt''

when I attempt the same thing in python, I also get an error.

**Python program:**

files = r"‪C:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt"

f = open(files, "r")

contents = f.read()

print(contents)

**output:**

"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe" "C:/Users/nkla/Desktop/ArcGIS Python Projects/Module01/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/nkla/Desktop/ArcGIS Python Projects/Module01/test.py", line 3, in 
f = open(files, "r")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt'

Comment: `\u202aC:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt` something wrong here, I think there is an unexpected character apprears in the begining, try remove your file path declaration, also the double quotes, type it again manually.

Comment: Hey Hùng, thank you for your comment. I am typing C:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt but somehow python is reading it as \u202aC:\Users\nkla\Desktop\lookingForMe.txt. In the c# code, another string directory is also added to the directory of the file.

Comment: Try to run with superuser (admin) privilege. Better use environment variable to avoid such problems.

Comment: Im not Python guy so no exp but you can look at here, I think it can resolve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267999/remove-u202a-from-python-string

Comment: @PrasanDutt can try, but that doesn't solve the problem. App should not be ran with super priv, and dev don't know why super priv resolve it

Comment: @HùngPhạmViệt I have given two options there. Let the developer try both and if it solves his/her problem.

Comment: @Ni Btw which text editor/IDE are you using (C#)? It might did some magic to your code, if you have enough free time, can open the cs file with Hex editor to see some thing hiding there. Ive got such situation with Json file a year ago

Comment: Retype the path, it seems that there is an invisible character before the C

Comment: try to put ur file .txt in same path as ur script and chnage the     files ="l‪ookingForMe.txt" and see what you get

Comment: For Python I am using PyCharm and for c# I am using Visual Studio Professional. I have tried retyping the path. I have not tried using admin rights. I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267999/remove-u202a-from-python-string and it looked like the solution was to use @"" for c# or r"" for python, but I am already doing this. I have never had problems using @"" in c# or r"" in python before. Thank you everyone for the help so far.

Comment: @MoetazBrayek hey, I tried that in both PyCharm and c#. Didn't work. In PyCharm I get the following error:  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\u202asample.txt' (I changed the txt name to sample) and in c# I get System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\nkla\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\‪lookingForMe.txt'.'

Comment: Excuse me everyone, I was copying the path from properties of the file -> Security -> Object name : ‪C:\Users\nkla\Desktop\Dragons.txt. I wasn't careful enough in my retyping. When I retype the path directly without any copying it solves the problem.