# Python Error code in Notebook, [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '.....\test python.xlsx'

Tags: python

I am trying to read an xlsx file using Pandas into Python.

I found out a problem, if you see the code. The first pd.read_excel() would work but the second one doesn't. Both are similar lines of codes, but the second pd.read_excel() just won't read the xlsx file

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r"D:\Users\act_gwj\Downloads\test python.xlsx") #- this will work
df = pd.read_excel (r"‪D:\Users\act_gwj\Downloads\test python.xlsx") # - this doesn't
print (df)
```

Error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aD:\\Users\\act_gwj\\Downloads\\test python.xlsx'
```

I am using Python 3.6.5 on Anaconda Notebook 32 bit. Pandas version 0.25.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like the site already has an answer to your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281061/1328439

Comment: I think you have Unicode characters in the second line.

Comment: Apparently yes, after retyping "D