# Error22 with plt.savefig()

Tags: python, matplotlib, jpeg

I'm trying to save a jpg in one of my files but I revice error 22 all the time. This is my code:

```
 buy_dir = r'‪C:/Users/Erik/Downloads/buy/'
 plt.savefig(buy_dir + str(uuid.uuid4())+'.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

And i receive this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:/Users/Erikb/Downloads/buy/f8365950-f1e8-4c46-b477-6b4c28d292a3.jpg'
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Remove `\u202a`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove u202a from Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267999/remove-u202a-from-python-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can try convert it with os.path.abspath

```
from os import path
plt.savefig(path.abspath(buy_dir + str(uuid.uuid4())+'.jpg'), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with running the first line (unicode error), seems like there is a weird character or something. When retyping the first line it worked fine for me:

```
buy_dir = r'C:/Users/Erik/Downloads/buy/'
plt.savefig(buy_dir + str(uuid.uuid4())+'.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```