# Recieving error when trying to read csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am tring to create a data frame from a csv file I downloaded. Using pandas I tried to read the file but is cannot manage to do so. I belive the code is correct but it is returning an OSError.

I tried turning the file path into a raw string, I tried using double backward slashes, i tried to change the name of the file as the "-" in "ml-100k" name could be the issue. nothing worked.

`import pandas as pd user = pd.read_csv(r"‪C:\Users\Luca\Documents\ml-100k/u.user", sep="|", names = ["User ID","Age","Gender","Occupation","Zip Code"])`

This returned an error of:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

`import pandas as pd user = pd.read_csv("‪C:/Users/Luca/Documents/ml-100k/u.user", sep="|", names = ["User ID","Age","Gender","Occupation","Zip Code"])`

This returned me an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    user = pd.read_csv("‪C:/Users/Luca/Documents/ml-100k/u.user", sep="|", names = ["User ID","Age","Gender","Occupation","Zip Code"])
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 950, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 605, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1442, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1735, in _make_engine
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 856, in get_handle
    handle = open(
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aC:/Users/Luca/Documents/ml-100k/u.user'
```

Please show me a way to format the filepath in order to be able to read the csv file. Thank you

Comment: Your file path should end with  a `.csv` not `.user`

Comment: Take a look at this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267999/remove-u202a-from-python-string
It looks like the \u202a character is the root of your problem