# Getting '\u202a' in front of my file path when looking for a csv file

Tags: python

I am currently using jupyter notebooks for a personal project and im trying to read a CSV file. I have the file path and it works in pycharm, but when i am in jupyter it adds a unicode "\u202a" in front of the filepath and it throws an exception "FileNotFoundError".

Here is my code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('‪T10Y2Y.csv')
print(data)
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267999/remove-u202a-from-python-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267999/remove-u202a-from-python-string)

Comment: That's the [Left To Right Embedding](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+202A) character. it could for instance reverse a right to left encoding character. How it got in your string, I'm not sure. And why pycharm was okay with it? Again,  don't know. I haven't bumped into this before, but it doesn't work on my linux machine from the shell either.